# Apache %{REQUEST_URI} not working correctly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I am not using Virtual Hosts or anything fancy though I have some .htaccess files setup. Following is my rewrite rule in httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/smsapi [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This rule basically says that if the uri does **not** begin with /app/smsapi then fire the rewrite. But when I restart the server and try it I get some weird results.

When I request the URL https://www.example.com/app/smsapi/index.php, I get a 200 Success code which is as expected. But, when I request the URL http://www.example.com/app/smsapi/index.php, it redirects to https://www.example.com/uri=/app/smsapi/index.php. So it actually fires the rule even though the request URI does not satisfy the condition.

So, then I decided to turn off the rewrite rules and give it a go. Now, both those URL give me a 200 Success code.

Now, I know this problem cannot be solved easily by other people who do not have access to the server, but am I right in saying that this is **certainly** a problem with REQUEST_URI not firing correctly? I have shown that without the rewrite rule, everything works normally, but with the rewrite rule, the second URL is redirected. Therefore, the redirection **must** be caused by the rewrite rule? Additionally, the condition for redirect rule is not satisfied. Doesn't this prove that there is something wrong with the functioning of the rewrite rule?

Is there any other possibility?

**UPDATE**
Something very weird is happening here. I setup a local server and tried the same rule and what I got for the URL http://192.168.0.112/app/ is

http://192.168.0.112/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/uri=/app/

which is correct because as long as the URL is not like /app/smsapi, it should redirect it. Wonder why this is not happening on the real server. Also, where you insert these rules seems to make a difference. (I am only including these rules after the LoadModule command).

On localhost, if I put these rules either above or below the Directory section, it won't work. But, if I include it **inside** the Directory section it will.

On server, if I include the rules inside the Directory section, they won't work. But, if I include them either above or below the Directory section, they start working.

This seems to me to be due to a difference in the versions. My localhost is an Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 running Apache 2.4.18. While the server is CentOS 6.8 running Apache 2.2.15.

But, i think the mystery as to why on the server redirect happens only once (though it is configured to go upto 20 times) has something to do with https. Which is also related to the original problem in which https is redirected even on a non-matching rule.

Clues anyone?

**UPDATE**
I updated the httpd.conf file with the same rules but I used http:// instead of https:// and it gave me the correct result with 20 redirects. That means I have isolated the problem to https.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the rule does fire over http, but not over https? If so, does the rule work as expected when navigating to a different url, like https://www.example.com/foo/bar ?

Comment: Hi Connor. Thanks for your reply. Yes, you understood correctly. And yes, I just tried it. Both with and without the rewrite rule, I can access www.example.com/git.html over http as well as https. So i think that confirms it.

Comment: Hi Connor. From experience, it's usually not something wrong with the software, especially a tried and tested software such as Apache, but with the configuration. Don't spend too much time over this. I will dig into it and update the question with what I find.

Answer (score 4):

You are reporting the exact issue in the first phrase: "I am not using Virtual Hosts or anything fancy though I have some .htaccess files setup"

.htaccess is "fancy" and overcomplicated, not virtualhosts.

If you had defined that RewriteCond in virtualhost in the first place it would work, but .htaccess is per-dir context (aka a nightmare) and the **regex ^/ will never match in that context**.

If you want to match REQUEST_URI in per-dir context (directory or .htaccess) you need to drop the initial slash, that is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^app/smsapi [NC]
```

Extra, also consider you MAY NOT need to add a RewriteCond for this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!app/smsapi)(.*) https://www.example.com/uri=$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi ezra-s. Thanks for your answer. I have used .htaccess but the RewriteRule was written in the httpd.conf file. The only .htaccess file I have is a very simple one. But, I get your point and I will attempt to eliminate the .htaccess file and then try to fetch the URL.

Comment: Alright @AshishK For the loops you may want to use a less greedy capture (.*) that rewrites all and then when the rewrite lands it is rewriten again and again and again.

Comment: @ezra-s kudos man, I had some simple rules drive me crazy due to the dir context... reading your answer I tried moving the rules in the VHost and everything works